# Trying to implement Patreon-only commands/functions on my discord bot, how would I accomplish this?

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot gives the role of 'Patreon' to my patreon supporters. This role is given on my main discord bot server. So right now I'm trying to write some commands that would be only available to users who have the role 'Patreon' in the BOTS discord server, how can I accomplish this?

Like is there a way I can be like -

message.member.has('Patreon Role').in('My Discord Server)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over the tasks you need to accomplish this.

1. Get the "home guild" with your users and corresponding Patreon role.
   *See [`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) and [`Map.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).*
2. Find the user in the guild.
   *See [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member).*
3. Check whether or not the user has the Patreon role.
   *See [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) and [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).*

You can define a function to help you out with this, export it and require it where you need it (or define it within relevant scope), and then call it to check if a user is one of your Patreon supporters.

Here's what this function would look like...

```js
// Assuming 'client' is the instance of your Discord Client.

function isSupporter(user) {
  const homeGuild = client.guilds.get('idHere');
  if (!homeGuild) return console.error('Couldn\'t find the bots guild!');

  const member = homeGuild.member(user);
  if (!member) return false;

  const role = member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Patreon');
  if (!role) return false;

  return true;
}
```

Then, as an example, using this function in a command...

```js
// Assuming 'message' is a Message.

if (!isSupporter(message.author)) {
  return message.channel.send(':x: This command is restricted to Patreon supporters.')
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message.member.roles.find('name', 'Patreon Role');//this returns either undefined or a role
```

What that does is it searches the users collection to see if the have "Patreon Role"

If the message is on the same server, otherwise you could do

```
client.guild.find('name','My Discord Server').member(message.author).roles.find('name', 'Patreon Role'); //this also returns undefined or a role
```

Clearly that second option is long, but what is basically does is searches the servers the bot is in for a server called 'My Discord Server' then it finds the GuildMember form of the message.author user resolvable, then it searches their roles for the role 'Patreon Role'

There is a chance it will crash though if they aren't on the server(the documentation doesn't say if it returns and error or undefined for some reason) so if it does crash you could instead do

```
  client.guild.find('name','My Discord Server').members.find('id', message.author.id).roles.find('name', 'Patreon Role'); //this also returns undefined or a role
```

You can read more here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

and here

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

and here

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild

Comment: Your current usage of [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) is deprecated; pass a function instead. If the member isn't in the server, the last snippet of code will still fail. `Guild.members.find(...)` will return `undefined`, and you'll get a TypeError for not being able to read property `roles` of `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, your answer also seems more reliable in all scenarios.  For a 100% reliable solution I recommend your response.  For a one line solution that will crash in an unexpected scenario you could use mine lol

Comment: Also, can't comment because I don't have enough rep, but I'd recommend on your response instead of `console.log('Couldn\'t find the bots guild!');` to use `console.warn('Couldn\'t find the bots guild!');` or `console.error('Couldn\'t find the bots guild!');`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Although both `stdout` and `stderr` will show up the same in the console, they could be configured differently in other environments so I've implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To try and give a full example, assuming this is in your message event

```js
if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Patreon') == undefined &&
    commandIsExclusive || message.guild.id !== 'this-id-for-BOTS-server') {
  // Don't allow them in here
}
```

Essentially, to run a command they must be a supporter, in a specific server and if it is exclusive and the other criteria aren't met, they are denied

Comment: Non-supporters will be able to run the command in guilds other than the one with the Patreon role.

Comment: With version 2, the member can be in any guild with a role named "Patreon" and they'll be treated as a real supporter. You can use IDs instead of names if you don't want to search the member's roles within the bots server.